# CakePHP 2 Models hasMany as hasOne

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I am trying to do this as MVC / CakePHP 2 as possible so if my approach is the incorrect, I would love to know (still learning). I feel like what I am doing should happen in the model and less so in the controller (to follow the fat model skinny controller principals).

I have a hasMany relationship between two tables:

```
trainings hasMany days.
```

If I want all the days in a training, this setup works as expected.

But I want (in every instance of training) the first day in a training. My thought process was to setup a hasOne relationship in the `Training` model as follows:

```
public $hasOne = array(
    ...
    'FirstDay' => array(
      'className' => 'Day',
      'foreignKey' => 'training_id',
      'fields' => 'FirstDay.training_date',
      'order' => array('FirstDay.training_date ASC'),
    )
);
```

In essence training hasOne days as `FirstDay`.

I assumed that with this setup, if I call a `Training` object I will get the associated `FirstDay`.

Instead I get multiple entries for `Training` -- one for each instance of days for a given training.  The SQL that gets output is as follows:

```
SELECT `Training`.`id`, `Training`.`course_id`, `Course`.`name`, ...  `FirstDay`.`training_date`
  FROM `tst`.`trainings` AS `Training`
  LEFT JOIN `tst`.`courses` AS `Course` ON (`Training`.`course_id` = `Course`.`id`)
  ...
  shortened for your benefit
  ...
  LEFT JOIN `tst`.`days` AS `FirstDay` ON (`FirstDay`.`training_id` = `Training`.`id`)
  WHERE 1 = 1 ORDER BY `FirstDay`.`training_date` ASC LIMIT 20
```

I was assuming that the hasOne would put a limit 1 instead of 20 in the above clause. Since it did not, I tried adding a `'limit' => 1` but that didn't work and the documentation does not mention that as an option in a hasOne relationship. I also do not understand why `WHERE 1 = 1` is there but I figure it does not matter since it is a true statement that does not limit anything -- just seems like unnecessary lifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship type `hasOne` is implemented with a `LEFT JOIN`, and therefore can't support `LIMIT` as an option, as it would affect the whole query (limiting not only `Day` but `Training` too).

There are several approaches to your problem. The most simple is to define your association as `hasMany`, but setting `'limit'=>1`.

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'FirstDay' => array(
        'className' => 'Day',
        'foreignKey' => 'training_id',
        'fields' => 'FirstDay.training_date',
        'order' => array('FirstDay.training_date ASC'),
        'limit' => 1
    )
);
```

Optionally, you then get rid of the extra numerical index `[0]` by using `Hash::map()` after the `find()`:

```
$this->Training->contain('FirstDay');
$trainings=$this->Training->find('all');

$trainings = Hash::map($trainings, "{n}", function($arr){
        $arr['FirstDay']=$arr['FirstDay'][0];
        return $arr;
    });
```

For other possible options, see:

- [Last x blog entries - but only once per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707048/last-x-blog-entries-but-only-once-per-user/11933591#11933591)
- [Method for defining simultaneous has-many and has-one associations between two models in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510464/method-for-defining-simultaneous-has-many-and-has-one-associations-between-two-m/2510476#2510476)

Comment: since is just one, maybe is easer to just do:
`$this->Training->contain('FirstDay');
$trainings=$this->Training->find('all');
$trainings = $trainings[0];` or maybe `$trainings=$this->Training->find('first');`

Comment: @lucho I think you've missed the point. The OP needs to retrieve one or more `Training`, but a single `Day`.

Comment: I swear I tried that... This looks like its going to work. Thank you Inigo! 

Nice little trick to clean up that index. I am not sure yet how I feel about it.